# Android RecyclerView duplicating images from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm writing a small group chat application in Android Studio and using Firebase as the backend. I'm trying to allow the users to post images however everytime I send an image to firebase storage and retrieve it in order to post into a recycler view using Glide, it duplicates in the recycler view. I've confirmed the image in the firebase storage is NOT duplicating, it's just on the recycler view on the app itself. I've been struggling with this issue for days and cannot for the life of me find why it's duplicating.

Here's my code:

**Uploads and Retrieves the image URL in Firebase**

```
public void uploadImage(final Uri filePath) {

    if (filePath != null) {
        final String pathToImage = "chatImages/" + user.getUid()+"/"+ UUID.randomUUID();

        StorageReference storeRef = storageReference.child(pathToImage);
        UploadTask uploadTask = storeRef.putFile(filePath);

        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Upload Failed");
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Upload Successful");
                //now that the image has been uploaded, send to chat
                storageReference.child(pathToImage).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        //adds photo, username and message to the arraylists\
                        imagePath = uri.toString();
                        Log.e(TAG, "done");
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to Retrieve Image Message");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Adds the image and other post info to the recycler view**

```
db.collection("chats").document("0fv4XvLpi8dWivyohQbk").collection("chatMessages")
            .orderBy("TimeStamp")
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Listen Failed", e);
                        return;
                    }
                    //temporay arraylists
                    final ArrayList<String> uIdAL = new ArrayList<>();
                    //gets any updates
                    for (DocumentChange newdoc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        if (newdoc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "new message" + newdoc.getDocument().getData());

                            //saves userIDs for later use in getting profile pics
                            uIdAL.add((String) newdoc.getDocument().getData().get("userID"));

                            //temporary profile picture
                            if(chatPhotoUrl != null && ((String) newdoc.getDocument().getData().get("userID")).equals(user.getUid()))
                            {
                                messageAvatars.add(chatPhotoUrl.toString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                messageAvatars.add("https://pictures.digitalrev.com/image/upload/v1454493563/gzev2fhfpoizg3bpozjr.jpg");
                            }

                            //get usernames and messages
                            userNames.add((String) newdoc.getDocument().getData().get("userName"));
                            messages.add((String) newdoc.getDocument().getData().get("message"));
                            imageMessages.add((String) newdoc.getDocument().getData().get("imageMessage"));

                            //add to recycler view
                            adapter.notifyItemInserted(userNames.size());
                            rv.scrollToPosition(userNames.size() - 1);

                            Log.e(TAG, "here");

                        }
                    }
                 }
            });
}
```

**Recycler View Adapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
private ArrayList<String> messageAvatars = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> userNames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> imageMessages = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> messageAvatars, ArrayList<String> userNames, ArrayList<String> messages, ArrayList<String> imageMessages, Context context) {
    this.messageAvatars = messageAvatars;
    this.userNames = userNames;
    this.messages = messages;
    this.imageMessages = imageMessages;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerviewitem,parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewholder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewholder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");
    //sets the fields in the recyclerview item
    Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(messageAvatars.get(position)).into(holder.messageImage);

    holder.userName.setText(userNames.get(position));
    holder.messageText.setText(messages.get(position));

    Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(imageMessages.get(position)).into(holder.imageMessage);
    //triggers if the recyclerview item is clicked
    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onClick: clicked");
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userNames.size();
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CircleImageView messageImage;
    TextView userName;
    TextView messageText;
    ImageView imageMessage;
    ConstraintLayout parentLayout;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        messageImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chatImageView);
        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernametextView);
        messageText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.messagetextView);
        imageMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentlayout);
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you add the Recycle view xml

Comment: Please show a SS of database...not sure you're creating child node of image and store url in it.

Comment: Have you tried to use only a [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) call instead of using the `addSnapshotListener`? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Hey, Have you solved the problem? I am facing the same issue.